# Sort Stack using vector

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, stack

I'm new to stacks and vectors. I'm trying to sort a stack using vector but I am facing an error. Please suggest how to solve this error

MY CODE

```
/* The below method sorts the stack s 
you are required to complete the below method */
void SortedStack :: sort()
{
  vector<int> st;
  while(!s.empty()){
      st.push_back(s.top());
      s.pop();
  }
  
  sort(st.begin(),st.end());
  
    for (auto itr = st.begin(); itr != st.end(); ++itr) {
      s.push(*itr);
  }


}
```

Error generated

```
Compilation Error:
Compilation Error
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void SortedStack::sort()’:
prog.cpp:61:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘SortedStack::sort(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator)’
   sort(st.begin(),st.end());
                           ^
prog.cpp:52:6: note: candidate: void SortedStack::sort()
 void SortedStack :: sort()
      ^
prog.cpp:52:6: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Comment: You have a method called `sort` which is hiding the `std::sort` function that you are trying to call. If you read the compiler error messages carefully it is telling you this. It's trying to call your `SortedStack::sort` method but that expects 0 arguments not the 2 you provided.

Comment: @john: Answers in the answers section please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort(st.begin(), st.end());` is an attempt to call your `sort` function and compilation fails as the parameters are incorrect.

`std::sort(st.begin(), st.end());` is a trivial fix.

The moral of the story is to *always* use `std::` explicitly, and drop `using namespace std;` &c.. Your code also becomes more readable as it's immediately obvious that you're using a function from the standard library.

Comment: what is the difference between these two statement??If i have used using namespace

Comment: @Garvit: Explicit scope resolution is required since your `sort` function is *shadowing* the one in the C++ standard library.